# Pyramid_beaker: session.type = cookie is not secure?

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

I've launched my site few days ago on Pyramid framework and I've choosed `session.type = cookie` with **pyramid_beaker** in perfomance reasons.
So in cookie I have encrypted user_id, it's look like this:

```
usr: "d79c098d69c26a4a85459acf03104ad74f3a22de1!userid_type:int" 
# for example here is encrypted id 1
```

And than I've tried to substitute cookie. I've logged in under id 2, changed it's cookie on previous one and now I'm automatically logged in under id 1!!!

Is it normal? Is it safe??? What for than encryption with it's super algorithms? So, some virus can steal some user's cookie and log in under his id? And where is the Security???

Could anyone explain me?
Thanks!

Comment: Wait, "changed it's cookie on previous one" = "changed cookie to 1's one"?

Comment: @Griwes I mean I've changed it on encrypted string from my example and it took it and now I am another user...

Comment: That's the way cookies work, you know. And that's the reason that cookies alone don't work safely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, session cookies are vulnerable to being stolen and being used to impersonate the logged-in user. You can minimize this risk to some extent by giving sessions a short lifespan, and/or by tying them to the client's IP address, but these are mere stumbling blocks to a dedicated hacker. The only real solution is to fully encrypt the session using SSL. This is why many popular sites (Gmail, Facebook, etc.) offer or require HTTPS sessions, and why the Firefox extension [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) exists.

Comment: So, my solution is to change type from cookie to (for example) database?

Comment: I've never used Pyramid, but generally even when a session is stored on the back end (i.e. a database on the server), some kind of session cookie is used to associate the user with their database record so that the framework doesn't need to authenticate the user on each request. This has the same vulnerability.

Comment: The only I can say is Great... But thanks for explaining, it helped a lot.

Comment: Note that due to recent TLS/SSL attack, even HTTPS is not secure against session hijacking ;) Google for: CRIME TLS